# Clear filter query before running next script

Tags: google-app-maker

### The Setup

I have a project table displaying values from a Calculated SQL data model. The table has edit buttons for each row that when clicked open a page fragment for editing the relevant project.

Because the display table is showing values from a Calculated SQL model, the edit button runs this query to load the underlying project record from the Cloud SQL source model.

```js
// onClick edit button event handler
var calcTableIds = widget.datasource.item.projectsTableId; // Calculated SQL model
var projectsTableIds = app.datasources.projects; // Cloud SQL model

projectsTableIds.query.filters.Id._equals = calcTableIds;
projectsTableIds.load();
app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.ProjectEdit);
```

### The Problem

The issue I'm having is that after a project record has been edited, subsequent functions I attempt to run that reference the Cloud SQL model only display results for the last edited project record.

I believe I need to run a script upon closing the project edit window that will reverse the query filter but I haven't been able to figure out a solution on my own.

FYI, the script I'm attempting to run after editing a project is the AMU Export function which should export all records from my Cloud SQL model to a spreadsheet but instead only exports the last edited record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#Query), you need to use the method **clearFilters()**. So when closing the fragment simply do:

```
app.datasources.THEDATASOURCE.query.clearFilters();
app.datasources.THEDATASOURCE.load();
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! FYI, it takes a bit for the filter to clear so if running a script directly after you may need to wrap it in a setTimeout() - this is what I had to do.

Comment: @bellwether I would actually recommend replacing `app.datasources.THEDATASOURCE.load()` with `app.datasources.THEDATASOURCE.unload()` that way there will not be any records loaded until your new filter is applied and the datasource is reloaded. Also, if you want to delay the dialog opening until the new record is actually loaded, then I would suggest implementing `projectsTableIds.load(function() {app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.ProjectEdit);});`. This will only open the dialog upon the successful reloading of the datasource.

Comment: Also note that clearing filters doesn't clear the "where" if you are using it, you have to set the where to "" as well.